# .htaccess redirect to url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want use `.htaccess` redirect to a php and passing some value with that.
like I have a page calls products.php and when I set `www.example.com/products.php?id=1111`
and it will goes to products with id 1111.

I'm desire to change the url become `www.example.com/products/1111.html`.

I have try put below in `.htaccess`:

```
# product
# /product/shortname.html
# product.php?id
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)(.*)\.html$   product\.php\?id=$1&type=deals   [QSA,L]
```

but it fail.

Comment: Regular expressions are only used in the pattern, not the substitution string – so while masking of the `.` and `?` (if they’re not meant to have their special meaning) in the first is required, in the second it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second group in brackets and don't escape dots and question mark in the 2-nd part of RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)\.html$   product.php?id=$1&type=deals   [QSA,L]
```

> I'm desire to change the url become
>   www.example.com/products/1111.html.

I didn't change `^product/` to `^products/`, as your php file is called "product.php". But you can do it easily.

Now when you input:

```
http://www.example.com/product/1111.html
```

it will be rewritten to:

```
http://www.example.com/product.php?id=1111&type=deals
```

Comment: appologize for my mistake, i think you know what i want right? could you provide more details about it, thanks

Comment: @frankyLoo More details about the syntax of RewriteRule? I updated the answer - there is no need to escape dots there. Plz, try the new version